# KVM and libvirt: How to configure a new disc device to an existing VM?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, libvirt, kvm-virtualization

I've got an Ubuntu 9.04 server running two VM's. In /etc/libvirt/qemu/machine1.xml two disk devices are defined like this:

```
<devices>
 <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
 <disk type='file' device='disk'>
   <source file='/vserver/machine1/disk0.qcow2'/>
   <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
 </disk>
 <disk type='file' device='disk'>
   <source file='/vserver/machine1/disk1.qcow2'/>
   <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
 </disk>
```

I need more storage space in at least one of the devices and thought about adding a third hdc device by simply adding one with same style as above and re-organising my mount structure (The virtual sizes of the current qcow2 files are unfortunately limited.)

My problem is that reloading libvirtd and restarting the VM do not result in a new visible device (checked with fdisk).

I'm aware of extending an existing qcow2 file (converting to raw format, cat-ing/adding the new one, using smth. like gparted) - but only as a last resort.

Hopefully it's something very simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in to the VM and shut it down.

Create a new virtual disk.

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 /vserver/machine1/disk2.qcow2 $SIZE
```

Force shut down the VM.

```
virsh destroy machine1
```

Open the VM configuration in your default editor.

```
virsh edit machine1
```

Add a new disk stanza like below.

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <source file='/vserver/machine1/disk2.qcow2'/>
    <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
</disk>
```

Close your editor. libvirt will automatically reload the configuration.

Start the VM.

```
virsh start machine1
```

Comment: "virsh destroy" is a little heavy handed, as it shuts the VM down ungracefully.  I'd advise graceful shutdown with "virsh shutdown" unless the VM is totally unresponsive.

Comment: "virsh shutdown" won't work if ACPI is not enabled in the libvirt config or a daemon like acpid is not properly configured and running in the guest. I've edited my instructions to include shutting down the guest first.

Comment: the current versions on qemu-kvm support disk hotplug, so shutdown shouldn't be needed. besides, using qcow2 on a flat image is a waste, and using ide is borderline criminal, when you have virtio